# different loops to show different post in same category

Tags: php, wordpress

I have got some problem in showing post.

what i have to do is i want to show post from a category but the condition is first post i want to show in different div in a loop.

Then second and third post of the same category i want show in another div in different  loop and rest of the post of the same category in another div and different loop.
i.e.

```
<div class="post1"> 1st post in the selected category </div>
<div class="post23"> 2nd and 3rd posts in selected  category </div>
<div class="post--"> rest all posts in selected category </div>
```

here is my code

```
 <?php $i = 0;
                $args = array( 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 19, 'numberposts' =>2000, 'order' => 'DESC');
                $myposts = get_posts( $args );
                foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
             if ($i ==1 ) { 

               ?>
            <li>
            <div class="cover_post">
             <div class="image_bl"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(320,245)); ?></div>
             <div class="content_hover">
              <h6>By : <?php the_author(); ?></h6>
             <h3 class="title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>
            <p> <?php //the_excerpt(); ?> <?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,70); ?> ...</p>
             <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a> 
             <a href="#">SHARE <span class="facebook_share"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/facebook_sh.png" alt=""  /></span> <span class="twitter_share"> <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/twit_sh.png" alt=""  /></span></a>
             </p>
             </div>
             <div class="content_hover content_hover1" style=" visibility:visible">
              <h6>By : <?php the_author(); ?></h6>
             <h3 class="title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h3>

             </div>
             <div class="clear"></div>

             </div>
             <div class="icon_post">

</div>
                 </li>
            <?php  $i++; }          
            endforeach;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
```

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition to the start of the loop. Something like:

```
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo '<div class="post1">';
        break;
    case 1:
    case 2:
        echo '<div class="post23">';
        break;
    default:
        echo '<div class="post">';
        break;
}
```

Then close the `</div>` at the end of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if($i == 0)
{
?>
    <div> Div for first post</div>
<?php
}elseif($i == 1 || $i == 2)
{

?>
    <div> Div for second and third posts</div>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
    <div> Div for rest posts</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I have used diffrent **Offset** value for this

```
 <?php 
     $args = array( '**offset**'=> 0, 'category' => 19, 'numberposts' =>1, 'order' => 'DESC');
     $myposts = get_posts( $args );
     foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );

 ?> 

  <?php 
         $args = array( '**offset**'=> 1, 'category' => 19, 'numberposts' =>2, 'order' => 'DESC');
         $myposts = get_posts( $args );
         foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
        { 
     ?>


<?php 
             $args = array( '**offset**'=> 3, 'category' => 19, 'numberposts' =>5, 'order' => 'DESC');
             $myposts = get_posts( $args );
             foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post );
            { 
         ?>
```